How exactly does the precise percentile ( pyspark.sql.functions.percentile ) function introduced in Spark 3.5.0 work?
We have a use case in PySpark for determining the percentile on a column in a dataset with billions of rows. Before upgrading to Spark 3.5.0, we've been using the percentile_approx Spark SQL function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html ), which as the name suggests provides an approximate percentile estimate given a precision setting. This was not great for us because it made our results not idempotent. So we were excited when in Spark 3.5.0 the precise percentile Spark SQL function came out ( https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#percentile ). We measured the performance with it, concerned that we might be hitting out of memory errors or just a lot of network traffic, given the nature of the task of determining the precise percentile on a dataset distributed amongst N executors, and it seemed no worse than the precise percentile.
So this seems like absolute magic - we can get precise percentile for a distributed dataset with no significant performance penalty. So we were curious how Spark achieves this, but we can't really find the source code for it. Could someone share either the source code or the algorithm?
Here is what we looked at so far:

Commit in Spark 3.5.0 which introduced the function ( https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/4ddf83f7f42a899947dfc711ced8b841cf3f6bab ). It seems though that this just introduces wrapper code over existing functionality that lives somewhere else, e.g. statements such as Column.fn("percentile", e, percentage, frequency) and new Percentile(e.expr, percentage.expr, frequency.expr), but we can't tell where the actual functional implementation of these is?
Pull request for this ( https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/41444 ) - again nothing substantial about how the problem is actually solved


Have a look at the Scala code of the percentile function.

@werner Thank you! Can you help me understand how did you know to go there? I looked at the code in the commit/PR, I don't see obvious way how to find the Scala code you are linking

In the commit that you posted in the question is also a change in sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala. This file imports the code that I linked in my first comment. If you are looking for details how the Python code connects to the JVM code this link is probably a good starting point.
